# Lost my MacBook Air two weeks ago and it still says offline on Find My iPhone!

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

Two weeks ago around 12 AM I lost my MacBook Air at the airport. At 9 AM I requested a lock on it using the Find My iPhone app but until now it is still pending.

I'm not entirely sure if I turned the location serves on my MacBook. I really want to find it but I don't know what to do. I have the serial number and everything but I heard that that won't help.

Can I still find it even if my Mac's location services isn't connected and is it possible that the thief could've restored my macbook using the guest user only?

Comment: Unless going to the police to signal the SN, you can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Find My iPhone on OS X doesn't require location services for locking/erasing the Mac, only to obtain its location. Therefore, next time the machine connects to the internet, it will lock. There's nothing you can do but wait until the device connects to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but I'm still wondering whether or not the their could've reformatted the laptop using the guest user? :)